# How to normalize a vector in r

Tags: r

I have a problem, I want to normalize a column in a dataframe in order to have this column with a standard deviation equal to 1. The sd() function return only one value of standard deviation but I want to have a normalize vector in return.

Example of my df :

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("1", "2", "3"), date_article = c("feb. 2021", "jan.2021", "dec. 2020"), occurences = c(3, 0, 1))
```

Someone can help me ? Thanks you in advance !

Comment: Use the `scale` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `scale` for normalization?

```
df$occurences <- scale(df$occurences)
```

such that

```
> df
  name date_article occurences
1    1    feb. 2021  1.0910895
2    2     jan.2021 -0.8728716
3    3    dec. 2020 -0.2182179
```

and

```
> mean(df$occurences)
[1] 1.84992e-17

> sd(df$occurences)
[1] 1
``
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's perfect. I did not know the scale function!

Comment: Last thing I don't see how to make, I need to standardize my vector in order to have a mean equal to 100. I don't see any parameter in scale function in order to make that. Someone know how to specify the mean of an existing vector ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @AlanCUZON what about `df$occurences <- scale(df$occurences) + 100`?